# How to display input field on mouseover

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have this JSF table which I use to display data and to edit data:

```
<table>
    <ui:repeat var="ud" value="#{DCProfileTabGeneralController.dcData}">

        <tr>
            <td>Datacenter Type</td>
            <td>
                <h:outputText value="#{ud.type}" 
                              rendered="#{not DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
                <h:inputText value="#{ud.type}" rendered="#{DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
            </td>                                    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date Added</td>
            <td>
                <h:outputText value="#{ud.dateAdded}" 
                              rendered="#{not DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
                <h:inputText styleClass="datepicker" value="#{ud.dateAdded}" rendered="#{DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
            </td>                                    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hour Added</td>
            <td>
                <h:outputText value="#{ud.hourAdded}" 
                              rendered="#{not DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
                <h:inputText value="#{ud.hourAdded}" rendered="#{DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
            </td>                                    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date Deployed</td>
            <td>
                <h:outputText value="#{ud.dateDeployed}" 
                              rendered="#{not DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
                <h:inputText styleClass="datepicker" value="#{ud.dateDeployed}" rendered="#{DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
            </td>                                    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hour Deployed</td>
            <td>
                <h:outputText value="#{ud.hourDeployed}" 
                              rendered="#{not DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
                <h:inputText value="#{ud.hourDeployed}" rendered="#{DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
            </td>                                    
        </tr>

    </ui:repeat>
</table>
```

This solution works fine but I want to extend it this way: I want to click on button which sets the edit flag to true. When I move the mouse over the value of the table the outputText to change to inputText.

And one more simple question. How I can add bottom padding to all fields globally?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `Richfaces` library and use `<rich:inplaceInput>` component as below.

```
<rich:inplaceInput value="hhhh" editEvent="onmouseover"/>
```

However if you still like to stick to `javascript` this is a concept.

```
<h:form id="myForm">
  <h:outputText value="aaa" id="outText"/><br/>
  <h:inputText value="aaa" style="display:none;" id="inText" />
</h:form>
```

This is the `javascript` code

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var outputText = document.getElementById("myForm:outText");
        var inputText = document.getElementById("myForm:inText");
        outputText.onmouseover = function() {
            outputText.style.display = 'none';
            inputText.style.display = '';
        }
        inputText.onblur = function() {
            outputText.style.display = '';
            inputText.style.display = 'none';
        }
    };
</script>
```

Since you are using a `ui:repeat`, you should change the `javascript` code accordingly.